# What is a back-reference in Java?

Tags: java

Especially in the context of `readUnshared()` method of `ObjectInputStream`,
what does a "back-reference" mean?

I came across the term in this

> If readUnshared is called to deserialize a **back-reference** (the stream representation of an object which has been written previously to the stream), an ObjectStreamException will be thrown.

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readUnshared()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you serialize objects using an `ObjectOutputStream`, the stream will 'remember' which objects it has already written. When it has to write the same object again, it will not write the whole object again, instead it will write an identifier that is called the 'back reference'.

The receiving `ObjectInputStream` will also keep track of what objects have been received, and will - upon reading a back reference - return the same object it read previously.

As explained in the [answer by CoronA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39696703/466862), this is - among others - used for serializing objects that point to each other, but also to ensure that identity equality in one JVM is preserved when serializing to another JVM.

The method `readUnshared` (and its counter part `writeUnshared`) are used to break away from this behavior: it ensures that the object read (written) will be unique (and not reused as a back reference). This is rather advanced and I can't remember ever having seen or having used it, but then again, I rarely see usage of serialization at all.

Answer (score 4):

Consider:

```
class A {
  B b;
}

class B {
  String s;
  A a;
}
```

and following construction:

```
A a = new A();
a.b = new B();
b.a = a;
```

If such a recursive structure is serialized and deserialized it should be functionally the same. `b.a` should not be an arbitrary instance of `A` but exactly the one which references b.

In this case `b.a` is the backreference, since A would be read before B in the `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: That isn't what a back-reference refers to. It has nothing to do with circular references, though they would greatly benefit from back-references.

Comment: Serializing a circular structure like that using `writeUnshared` would throw a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: From my point of view there are several scenarios where backreferences are needed. And circular references are part of them. Yes - writeUnshared will probably fail, but at the time I wrote this answer nobody mentioned readUnshared.

Comment: Yes, I agree that back-references are needed for circular references, but I don't agree that back-references **are** circular references. You showed an example of a structure that would need back-references to work, but didn't explain what a back-reference is.

Answer (score 1):

A back-reference is a reference to an identical object which was already previously written/read to the stream. Think of it like a pointer to a previous object in the stream.

Back-references are useful since they greatly reduce the footprint of the object if it is (de)serialized multiple times in the same stream, and also allow for reference equality when deserialized.

Using back-references:

```
Object obj = new Object();
obj == obj // true
writeObject(obj);
writeObject(obj);
Object obj1 = readObject();
Object obj2 = readObject();
obj1 == obj2 // true
```

If we weren't using back-references, the final statement would be `false`.